# Problemas despues de instalar servicios ssh en ubuntu: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ssh

estaba montando un contenedor de docker y he instalado  ssh para acceder desde afuera en condiciones. Una vez instalado he ido ha arrancar el servicio ssh : `sudo service ssh start`, y me ha dado los siguientes WARNING que me impiden iniciar el servicio:

```
root@54b791baafcd:~/.ssh# service ssh start
 * Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd                                                                                                                                              @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
sshd: no hostkeys available -- exiting.
```

Como podria solucionar este inconveniente ? He buscado por internet y he visto que cambiando unos permisos, los he cambiado pero nada. Al ser un contenedor de docker estoy trabajando siempre con root, por eso si no veis el sudo en los comandos, que sepais eso.

Os pongo aqui el directorio con su contenido y sus permisos de los warning que me dan:

```
root@54b791baafcd:/etc/ssh# ls -ls
total 548
524 -rw-r--r--+ 1 root root 535195 May 29  2020 moduli
  4 -rw-r--r--+ 1 root root   1603 May 29  2020 ssh_config
  0 drwxr-xr-x+ 1 root root      0 May 29  2020 ssh_config.d
  4 -rw-r--r--+ 1 root root    513 Dec 16 16:39 ssh_host_ecdsa_key
  4 -rw-r--r--+ 1 root root    411 Dec 16 16:39 ssh_host_ed25519_key
  4 -rw-r--r--+ 1 root root   2602 Dec 16 16:39 ssh_host_rsa_key
  4 -rw-r--r--+ 1 root root    342 Dec 16 16:39 ssh_import_id
  4 -rw-r--r--+ 1 root root   3289 May 29  2020 sshd_config
  0 drwxr-xr-x+ 1 root root      0 May 29  2020 sshd_config.d
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las llaves privadas deberían tener 600 en permisos (rw para el usuario, grupo y otros grupos no deberían poder verlas).

`sudo chmod 600 /etc/ssh/blabla_key` debería servir

Lo otro, como sugerencia, añade a un usuario no root al grupo de docker como lo indica la documentación. Siempre es más sano evitar andar por ahí como root :)

`sudo usermod -aG docker el-usuario-que-no-es-root`

Comment: Perfecto, oye una preguntita. Desde un pc cliente estoy intentando conectarme como root ( aunque luego voy a crear un usuario no root para docker siguiendo tu consejo) mediante ssh a un puerto en concreto ´ssh root@loquesea -p puerto´ pero me pide una password luego, pero el user root es del docker. Y no tiene password, he intentado dejarlo vacio pero no me da acceso. Como podria arreglar esto ?

Comment: A ver: estás intentando conectarte por SSH a un contenedor? Tendrías que revisar que `loquesea` sí sea la IP correcta (por defecto va a quedar en la LAN que crea docker y ahí no será visible sin más). Puedes mapear el puerto 22 del contenedor a algún puerto del host (algo como `-p 22002:22` y el puerto de la izquierda en el host expondría el 22 del contenedor). Ahí sí, llegarle al root *del contenedor* con ssh apuntando al puerto 22002 de la máquina host...

Comment: Esta todo mapeado ya, el puerto de BD, el ssh, el 80,  pero hasta he desabilitado la contraseña para ssh y aun asi me pide una.

Comment: Si mi respuesta resuelve la pregunta inicial, acéptala y abre OTRA pregunta con tu otra pregunta, así nos muestras cómo estás arrancando el contenedor y podemos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: he creado este grupo : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117349/duda-de-docker . Para no crear una pregunta que es mas una idea. No sabia como invitarte desde la sala,por eso la pongo aqui